# recharts stacked bar chart with overlapping cells

Tags: stacked-chart, recharts, stacked-area-chart

I'd like to present a comparison of response times - percentiles for product A and B, example data:

```
[ { "category": "X", "A.90th": 100, "A.50th": 50, "B.90th": 120, "B.50th": 40 },
  { "category": "Y", "A.90th": 250, "A.50th": 60, "B.90th": 200, "B.50th": 80 } ]
```

This should display two stacked bars (for product A and B) in each category, total 4 bars, each having two cells (ok, in practice there would be more datapoints than just 90th and 50th percentile). My point is that I don't want the response times be 'summed' (100 + 50, 120 + 40...) but overlapping as the 90th percentile is always > 50th percentile.

Is there a way to achieve this with recharts? I could naturally recalulate the data to be only 'diffs', but then I'd have to heavily customize `Tooltip`.